# Prevent jQuery accordion from adding ui-state-active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jQuery accordion and want to have the selected panel looking different to the jQuery UI. To realize this, I don't want to have the class "ui-state-active" on the active Header - and i don't know how to realize this.

My current try:

```
$('#MyAccordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0,
    activate: function () {
        $('#MyAccordion h3').removeClass("ui-state-active");
    },
    create: function () {
       $('#MyAccordion h3').removeClass("ui-state-active");
    },
    beforeActivate: function () {
       $('#MyAccordion h3').removeClass("ui-state-active");
    }
});
```

JS Fiddle Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/u2c6zcy6/1/

You can see, the header of the selected panel is getting white for a moment right before the class is being removed again. But how can I prevent the panel header from getting white (getting the class ui-state-active) at all?

Comment: hi add the css class-
`.ui-accordion-header-active { background: lime; }`
in your style

Comment: why? Depending on other Parameters I set different css classes on the different h3-headers in my accordion. I want these classes to remain visible, even when the h3 header ist active. So that is why I have to remove ui-state-active here.

Comment: if you not want to change the class the you update your active event handler like 
`activate: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui).addClass("ui-state-active");
        }'
and in css change `background-color` to `background`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add also click event listener:

```
$('#MyAccordion').on('click', '.ui-accordion-header',   function(e){
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
});
```